# How to style each option of react-select component differently?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I'm using react-select v2 (2.41).
I have 3 options set and I want to set background color of each option to different color. Is this possible and how?

I've tried with styles like this:

```
const customStyle = {
    option: (base, state) => ({
        ...base,
        backgroundColor: "red",
    })
};
<Select
    ...
    options={options}
    styles={customStyle}
 />
```

but this changes color of all options to the same color. What I want is for each option to have different background color.
Something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `component` props to setup a background color base on your options `props` like this:

```
const Option = props => {
  return (
    <div style={{ backgroundColor: props.data.color }}>
      <components.Option {...props} />
    </div>
  );
};
const options = [
  { label: "Option 1", value: 1, color: "red" },
  { label: "Option 2", value: 2, color: "orange" },
  { label: "Option 3", value: 3, color: "green" }
];

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Select options={options} components={{ Option }} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Like in this [live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/jl8r4oqx1v).

Comment: Thank you, this is what I wanted.

Answer (score 5):

One more way to achieve what you are trying to do is with react select styles

documentation: https://react-select.com/styles

example:

```
const colorsArray = [
    { label: "Option 1", value: 1, color: '#FF8B8B' },
    { label: "Option 1", value: 2, color: '#ABFF8B' },
    { label: "Option 1", value: 3, color: '#80CEAC' },
];

const colorStyles = {
    option: (styles, { data }) => {
        return {
            ...styles,
            backgroundColor: data.color,
        };
    },
};

<Select
    value={colorsArray[0]}
    options={colorsArray}
    styles={colorStyles}
/>
```

[live exmaple](https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-select-custom-option-background-color-wbfdy)

Answer (score 4):

What about using `:nth-child()` CSS selector?

```
<Select
    ...
    className="myclass"
    classNamePrefix="myclass"
    options={options}
    styles={customStyle}
 />

// CSS
.myclass__value-container:nth-child(1) {
    // rules
}
.myclass__value-container:nth-child(2) {
    // rules
}
.myclass__value-container:nth-child(3) {
    // rules
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very useful, just instead of 'value-container' I used 'option' and get what I need.
 Like in this [live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/l541339q19) .